# Linux shell scripting: How can I remove final numbers in a word list file?

Tags: linux, shell

I have this example list text file (**one word per line**):

```
John
J0hn
John45
Smith
Sm1th
Jane
Jane333
Doe555
```

And I want to **obtain**:

```
John
J0hn
Smith
Sm1th
Jane
Doe
```

This is: I would like to **remove numbers to the end of the words** (note that numbers inside words are allowed) and then remove **duplicates**.
I have some experience in programming, so I could implement some loop/s to check for those numbers, and then another loop/s to remove duplicate words, but I think the Linux Shell must have some simple **commands or parameter expansions** that could solve this for me.

Removing original **file sorting** is a possibility, but it would be fine if some method does not require it.

**Possible usage**:

- Isolating words used in passwords databases (John, 45John, 12345John) to obtain statistics of diversity.

Ideas are welcome. Thanks you.

EDIT-1: whitespaces are not expected in this kind of "dictionary" text files (thanks you anyway, @rottweilers_anonymous).

EDIT-2: Added example of a possible ambiguity, a "word" that has only numbers: it must be left (I know, I know, that is not strictly a "word" ;-) ). Example original file:

```
John
J0hn
John45
Smith
Sm1th
Jane
Jane333
Doe555
12345
```

As long as a line like `12345` (numbers without word) is not really a `number to the end of a word`, I would like to keep it, so the results must be:

```
John
J0hn
Smith
Sm1th
Jane
Doe
12345
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple way would be with `sed` and `uniq`:

```
sed "s/\([^0-9]\)[0-9]*\s*$/\1/" file | uniq
```

This does assume that the names are in order. If they aren't, you can use `sort`:

```
sed "s/\([^0-9]\)[0-9]*\s*$/\1/" file | sort -u
```

EDIT: per @rottweilers_anonymous suggestion, added the check for white space at the end of line.

EDIT: per OP's modification of question conditions, don't remove numbers from line that is only numbers.

Comment: I would suggest bulletproofing this solution by preparing for potential whitespace: `sed "s/[0-9]*\s*$//" file | sort | uniq`

Comment: Well, whitespaces not expected in my case, but it is good to know. Thanks you, @rottweilers_anonymous .

Comment: @rottweilers_anonymous indeed, thanks for the suggestion. It does beg the question whether `John20 30` should be reduced to `John`...

Comment: Added extra info to OP about ambiguity in lines with only numbers. Please, read.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez, ok I have made anothe redit to take care of that case.

Comment: The answer is correct, but seems to have some problems running on CygWin with special characters like '!', '$', or '\' in the text file: `Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character`. Of course, this should be some problem with CygWin, and works fine on Ubuntu. Furthermore, using `sed` should be the more portable solution of all.

Comment: Or use `sort -u` in lieu of `sort | uniq`.  Note that the sample input data is not in sorted order (or not in a sufficiently sorted order for a simple `uniq` to work): `John` precedes `J0hn` precedes `John45`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, thanks, I forgot about the -u. I didn't look closely at the original at first, so you're correct that the correct solution in this case requires the `sort`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ perl -ne '/^\d+$/ or s/\d+$//;$names{$_}++;END{print sort keys %names} ' file
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
12345
Doe
J0hn
Jane
John
Sm1th
Smith
```

Comment: Added extra info to OP about ambiguity in lines with only numbers. Please, read.

Comment: For those interested: working fine on CygWin, even with special characters like '!', '$', or '\' in the text file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's `awk` in action - this also retains original order

```
awk '/[^[:digit:]]/{sub(/[[:digit:]]+$/, "")};!a[$0]++' file
John
J0hn
Smith
Sm1th
Jane
Doe
12345
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is a possible ambiguity: long as a line like `12345` (numbers without word) is not really a `number to the end of a word`, I would like to keep it. Could you please modify your command?

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez, addressed that

Comment: Working fine on CygWin too. Even with special characters like '!', '$', or '\' in the text file.