# Linux shell scripting: How can I remove initial numbers in a word list file?

Tags: linux, shell, numbers

I have this example list text file (**one word per line**):

```
John
J0hn
45John
Smith
Sm1th
Jane
333Jane
555Doe
12345
```

And I want to **obtain**:

```
John
J0hn
Smith
Sm1th
Jane
Doe
12345
```

This is: I would like to **remove numbers to the end of the words** (note that numbers inside words are allowed) and then (as long as the line is the same) remove **duplicates**.
Note that only numbers before letters must be deleted, so `12345` will remain in the list.
I have some experience in programming, so I could implement some loop/s to check for those numbers, and then another loop/s to remove duplicate words, but I think the Linux Shell must have some simple **commands or parameter expansions** that could solve this for me.

Removing original **file sorting** is a possibility, but it would be fine if some method does not require it.
**Whitespaces** are not expected in this kind of "dictionary" text files.

Ideas are welcome. Thanks you.

Intended use:

- Isolating words used in **passwords databases** (John, 45John, 12345John) to obtain statistics of diversity.

> Note: this [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712606/linux-shell-scripting-how-can-i-remove-final-numbers-in-a-word-list-file) could help anyone trying to
>   answer. I am not sure about the syntax with `perl`, `awk` and `sed`,
>   so I prefer to ask instead of doing myself some strange mod that could
>   result in disaster.

Comment: What if there are numbers before the word and inside the word, e.g. `1234Jo7n`?

Comment: You probably forgot one of the Johns ;).

Comment: @Barmar, such `1234Jo7n` must become `Jo7n`. Numbers in the middle are not a problem. And numbers at the end are treated on the refered link.

Answer (score 4):

You can use sed for this:

```
sed -r 's/^[0-9]+(.*[^0-9].*)$/\1/g'
```

If I run this on your file, I got:

```
John
J0hn
John
Smith
Sm1th
Jane
Jane
Doe
12345
```

You can then use `perl` [to filter out duplicates](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11939/how-to-get-only-the-unique-results-without-having-to-sort-data):

```
sed -r 's/^[0-9]+(.*[^0-9].*)$/\1/g' | perl -ne 'print unless $seen{$_}++'
```

Which gives:

```
John
J0hn
Smith
Sm1th
Jane
Doe
12345
```

Comment: Not working with any other character than `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]`, for example `45John-`. Original post proposal is `Whitespaces are not expected`, but nothing is told about any other character.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez: modified, fixed I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the sed answer, which is going to be really fast, but just for fun here's an answer in pure posix shell, since your question was about **shell** scripting:

```
while read i; do
    o="$i"
    while 1; do
       l=${i#[0-9]}
       [ "$l" == "$i" -o -z "$l" ] && break
       i="$l"
   done
   [ -z "$i" ] && echo "$i" || echo $o
done < file.txt
```

(Okay, I cheated, [ (aka /bin/test) is not always a built-in command.)

Comment: Very nice answer. Indeed the question is about shell scripting, but almost all shell scripts I've ever seen make use of other programs. After all, the task of a shell is to group user programs together, not to provide a new programming environment :).

Comment: You're completely right! I did that only for entertainment, sane people should use sed :P

Comment: Not only for entertainment, @serialk. Your answer could be very useful for me in some embedded environments, like routers. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
sed -r 's/^[0-9]+([A-Za-z])/\1/g' | sort -u
```

The regexp matches a sequence of digits at the beginning of the line followed by a letter. The capture group gets the letter, and the whole match is replaced by the letter.

Piping to `sort -u` gets rid of the duplicates.

Comment: Not working with any other character than `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]`, for example `45John-`. Original post proposal is `Whitespaces are not expected`, but nothing is told about any other character.